# Rate at which a object moves away from a point P

Tags: calculus, geometry

I've got a point P at $0,0,0$ and an object O at a point $4,10,5$ and has a velocity vector of $-8,15,0.5$ on it.

I can calculate the distance between P and O, after that however... I get stuck.

How do I find the rate at which the object is moving away from point P?

Comment: Derive an equation for the change in the distance. You can calculate the distance at any point (with Pythagoras), then you just need to calculate the time derivative of that and insert the values to the result.

Comment: The rate at which the object O is moving away from point P is simply a derivative of their distance with respect to time: $$\frac{d\, |\overline{OP}|}{d\,t}$$

Comment: If you want the relative velocity only at one time, there is another way other than calculus. You could find the component of the overall velocity vector that is parallel to the vector between the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to know the radial component $\vec{v}_r$ of the velocity vector $\vec v$ at the given point.

So, project the velocity vector onto the radial vector $\vec{OP}$:
$$\vec{v}_r =  \left( \vec v \cdot \frac{\vec{OP}}{|\vec{OP}|}\right) \frac{\vec{OP}}{|\vec{OP}|} = \frac{\vec v \cdot \vec{OP}}{|\vec{OP}|^2}\vec{OP} $$

- radial vector $\vec{OP} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 10 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$
- squared length $|\vec{OP}|^2 = 4^2+10^2+5^2 = 141$
- radial component at $P$:
  $$\vec{v}_r = \frac{\vec v \cdot \vec{OP}}{|\vec{OP}|^2}\vec{OP} = \frac{1}{141} \left(\begin{pmatrix} −8 \\ 15 \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 10 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} \right)\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 10 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{241}{282}\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 10 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$$

If you are not interested in the direction, then just calculate $|\vec{v}_r|$.

Comment: I don't think the radial component is what I'm after. What I'm wanting to know is from the perspective of point P, how quickly is O moving towards or away from it given the position of the of the object and the velocity vector.

Comment: Hmmm. At least in your post you ask how fast it is moving away from $P$ which is the origin. I interpreted this as the velocity component that points "directly away from the origin". And this is the radial component of the velocity vector.

Comment: Would your answer still work considering the object O has the velocity vector on it?

Comment: The given answer is based on $O$ moving with respect to $P(0,0,0)$. So, it is exactly for the case that $O$ "has the velocity vector on it". Maybe we interpret the problem in two different ways but one does not see, how the other one sees it.

Comment: Btw., it is quite common to decompose a movement into a radial and a tangential component. The radial component describes the movement away or towards the fixed center of observation.

Comment: The calculation above corresponds to the green arrow in the picture you find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_velocity

Comment: Ahhhh makes sense now. Will give it a go with the other coordinates I have for P, as I need to look at it from 4 different positions. Thanks mate!

Comment: The formula I needed was very similar in that it didn’t need to be multiplied by the vector OP again. Thanks heaps mate!